# Treeview with jQuery, AJAX, MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I am stuck in applying tree view. Can somebody help me? I use a `codeigniter`. I'm just thinking how to make a tree view using `jQuery with AJAX` in `Codeigniter framework` if I have this kind of tables in `MySQL`:

project table

```
ID ProjectName
1  Project 1
2  Project 2
3  Project 3
```

stagelist table

```
ID  StageID  ProjectID
1   1        1
2   2        1
3   3        2
4   4        2
5   5        3
6   6        3
```

stage table

```
ID StageName
1  Stage 1
2  Stage 2
3  Stage 3
4  Stage 4
5  Stage 5
6  Stage 6
```

if I link all the table:

```
project.ID = stagelist.ProjectID
stage.ID = stagelist.SatgeID
```

My HTML:

```
<div id="project_structure_tab">
    <div id="result_batch_structure">

    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$( "#project_structure_tab" ).click(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
    url : '<?php echo base_url()?>project/get_proect_list',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { 
            project_id: $('#project_id').val()
          },
    success: function(msg){
              //here will show how to execute a tree view based on the table linking from model
            }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you reading about [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ajqgriddocs). It's very good solve to display tree tables and i'm using it. Some time ago i found recursion treeview in codeigneter [here](http://tlorentzen.dk/recursion-treeview-in-codeigniter/), may be it help you too.

Comment: Sorry, but i can't share this code. If you ask about jqGrid it have many samples here http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html.